# Android Google Cloud protobuf java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:No static method checkNotNull((Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class

Tags: android, google-cloud-pubsub

Using Android Studio 3.0.1, Try to pull messages from Gloogle Cloud PubSub module, using the next code to retrieve the messages:

PullMessage.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.okhttp.NegotiationType;
import io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder;
import io.grpc.auth.MoreCallCredentials;

import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PullRequest;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PullResponse;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ReceivedMessage;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.SubscriberGrpc;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class PullMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    ProgressBar pb = null;
    ListView lwListado;
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    Integer numMessages;
    private List<String> arrayList;

    public void setContext(Context ctx){
        context=ctx;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pb = (ProgressBar)     ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Bajando mensajes de la subscripcion:  "+MainActivity.SUBSCRIPTION, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String...params){
        try{

            Log.d(TAG, "Leyendo archivo de credenciales: "+MainActivity.CREDENTIALS_FILE);
            AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
            InputStream isCredentials =     am.open(MainActivity.CREDENTIALS_FILE);
            ManagedChannel channelImpl = OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress("pubsub.googleapis.com",443).negotiationType(NegotiationType.TLS).build();

            Log.d(TAG, "Canal Terminado?:"+ channelImpl.isTerminated());

            GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(isCredentials);
            credential = credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub"));

            SubscriberGrpc.SubscriberBlockingStub subscriberBlockingStub =  SubscriberGrpc.newBlockingStub(channelImpl).withCallCredentials(MoreCallCredentials.from(credential));

            PullRequest pullRequest = PullRequest.newBuilder()
                .setSubscription( MainActivity.SUBSCRIPTION )
                .setReturnImmediately( true )
                .setMaxMessages(10)
                .build();

            PullResponse pullResponse = subscriberBlockingStub.pull(pullRequest);
            numMessages = pullResponse.getReceivedMessagesCount();
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of messages received: " + String.valueOf(numMessages));
            for (ReceivedMessage message1 : pullResponse.getReceivedMessagesList()) {
                PubsubMessage pubsubMessage1 = message1.getMessage();
                arrayList.add(pubsubMessage1.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "Message received (ID="+message1.getAckId()+"): " + pubsubMessage1.toString());
        }

        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Excepcion: "+e.toString());
        }
        return 0;
    }

    //@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer num){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer num){
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        final ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        lwListado.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Number of messages received: " + String.valueOf(num) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

The code receive  an error in execution time, in the line:

```
PullResponse pullResponse = subscriberBlockingStub.pull(pullRequest);
```

The complete error stack is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.example.arkmind_2.googlecloud, PID: 2769
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
               Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: Failed to read message.
                  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:221)
                  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:202)
                  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:131)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.SubscriberGrpc$SubscriberBlockingStub.pull(SubscriberGrpc.java:897)
                  at com.example.arkmind_2.googlecloud.PullMessage.doInBackground(PullMessage.java:92)
                  at com.example.arkmind_2.googlecloud.PullMessage.doInBackground(PullMessage.java:47)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method checkNotNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/protobuf/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.protobuf.Internal' appears in /data/app/com.example.arkmind_2.googlecloud-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                  at com.google.protobuf.MapField$MutatabilityAwareMap.put(MapField.java:334)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.<init>(PubsubMessage.java:66)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.<init>(PubsubMessage.java:14)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(PubsubMessage.java:1197)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(PubsubMessage.java:1192)
                  at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:497)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.ReceivedMessage.<init>(ReceivedMessage.java:61)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.ReceivedMessage.<init>(ReceivedMessage.java:13)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.ReceivedMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(ReceivedMessage.java:752)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.ReceivedMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(ReceivedMessage.java:747)
                  at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:497)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.PullResponse.<init>(PullResponse.java:56)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.PullResponse.<init>(PullResponse.java:13)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.PullResponse$1.parsePartialFrom(PullResponse.java:874)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.PullResponse$1.parsePartialFrom(PullResponse.java:869)
                  at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:90)
                  at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
                  at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$2.parseFrom(ProtoLiteUtils.java:179)
                  at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$2.parse(ProtoLiteUtils.java:171)
                  at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$2.parse(ProtoLiteUtils.java:88)
                  at io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.parseResponse(MethodDescriptor.java:266)
                  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:526)
                  at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
                  at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
                  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$ThreadlessExecutor.waitAndDrain(ClientCalls.java:626)
                  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:122)
                  at com.google.pubsub.v1.SubscriberGrpc$SubscriberBlockingStub.pull(SubscriberGrpc.java:897) 
                  at com.example.arkmind_2.googlecloud.PullMessage.doInBackground(PullMessage.java:92) 
                  at com.example.arkmind_2.googlecloud.PullMessage.doInBackground(PullMessage.java:47) 
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9aa1e520: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9aa23950)
```

The most interesting part is the line:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method checkNotNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/protobuf/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.protobuf.Internal' appears in /data/app/com.example.arkmind_2.googlecloud-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
```

The program use protobuf lite, but seems like something is missing.

Comment: How are you declaring your gradle dependencies?

Comment: Did you try to follow this documentation [ https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous-pull ] that explains how to do a Cloud Pub/Sub pull?

Comment: The code below is from a proyect of github, but, has a lot of problems with library versions and dependences because is old, is the only complete example I found. The link you mentioned seems interesting but only include fragments of code that is too complicated to include in the rest of my project, many things aren't compatible without massive changes.